# Adding functions to redux store within reducer is an anti pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

say I have a component connected to the redux store. Within this store, there's a list of objects. For instance something like this:

```
ReduxStore: {
    dataList: [
      {name:'bla'},
      {name:'blub'},
    ]
}
```

Is it actually an anti pattern to create and add a filter function within the reducer to  create something like this:

```
ReduxStore: {
   dataList: {
     data:[
      {name:'bla'},
      {name:'blub'}
     ],
     isNameAvailable: (name) => {/* search for name */}
   }
}
```

It works great, but I'm not sure whether this was the intended way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an anti-pattern because your store only cares about data, not computation. Once you start adding functions to your store, you lose the ability to serialize the data inside it.

However, it's pretty trivial to pull these kinds of helper functions out and turn them into standalone utility selectors which you can use to achieve the same thing.

```
function isNameAvailable(store, name) {
  /* search for `name` in `store` */
}
```

Now the function works independently of the store and you can keep them separate for testing.

From here, you can take a look at [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) which allows you to turn your `isNameAvailable` function into a cached selector, meaning you'll only need to re-calculate as and when the appropriate data in the store is changed.

Answer (score 2):

From [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions):

> It’s very important that the reducer stays pure. Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> - Mutate its arguments;
> - Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
> - Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

so I think if you want to declare a filter function `isNameAvailable`, in my opinion, you have two options:

- use the connect function to filter

  ```
  // the solution of connect 

  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';

  const App = () => (
    <div>the example</div>
  );

  function isNameAvailable(state) {
    // your code
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return isNameAvailable(state)
  }

  module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
  ```
- declare a filter function in action

In my experience，I think the first one is better. I hope this can help you.